# XCODE: how to toggle between 2 specific projects out of many open projects in Xcode

Tags: xcode7

I can toggle/switch between open Xcode projects using 'CMD'+ '~'.
But my question is,
I have more than 2 projects open ( about 6), however I would like to toggle between specific 2 ios/swift projects.
The reason being, I am referencing 1 of the project and writing code into my project. It just annoys when I do CMD + ~ and the xcode keeps going to open project of its own choice.

Is there anyway to do this? I am using Xcode 7.

Comment: Minimize those you don't need, ie. put them in the dock.

Comment: sorry how do I minimise those multiple projects from 'Open Recent' menu or from the Dock? Do you mean open each project and minimise ? I have quite a lot of projects open, currently 6, but sometime >10

Comment: If you click the yellow button in the upper left corner it will be placed in the dock and the switching will only happen between the projects that are not minimized.

Comment: great thanks, but  should the minimize  be done one at a time for each project?. And if there are 10 projects that has to be minimised out of 12 so that I switch between the 2 , do i need to minimise the other 10 manually by opening each one?

Comment: If you need to have ten projects open at the same time and only want to switch between two then yes, you need to manually minimize the other eight. But it's more a user interaction question and not a programming question.

Comment: ok cheers, thanks very much. sorry I didnt get this information anywhere else and hence posted in SO

Comment: No problem. You can also use the keyboard shortcut cmd+m to minimize.

Comment: Thats brilliant , cheers ! cmd + m helps !